# StackOverflow-ify

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, style

#### About:

This is a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script that re-styles an SE site to look like stackoverflow.com

#### Download / Install:

You can install either the site or the chat version on [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en) (works with Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey)

[Install Site Version](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34034-so-ify)

[Install Chat Version](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34036-so-ify-chat)

#### Code:

This is a JS script, so it's easy to modify if you want.

You can find the source code for both here: [Site Version](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34034-so-ify/code) - [Chat Version](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34036-so-ify-chat/code)

This script is very minimal and there is no promise it will work on *every* site. The more customized a site is, the less this will work (photo.se for example). If you have need of a specific site to be accounted for, let me know and I may be able to add some code to handle it.

Comment: Just a trick for overriding CSS styles: If you append the `<link>` to the `document.documentElement` just after the `<body>` is created, your styles with the same specificity will be the ones applied to the document, because they come last. You can watch for the creation of the `<body>` with a `MutationObserver`. You also need to watch for it using timer polling, because Edge doesn't correctly handle a `MutationObserver` on the `document.documentElement`.